# Magento : How to implement a menu created with jquery to magento?

Tags: magento, menu

I am using magento 1.7.0.2. I create a simple navigation (top navigation) menu for categories and sub-categories with jquery and css for my website and i wish to implement it in my magento.
How can i do that and it's possible ?

Comment: do you want to replace existing or adding new menu?

Comment: i want to replace existing menu

Comment: you have to override the navigation

Comment: This is basic one.. go through the links provided in this [post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7944/2960)

Answer (score 1):

if You want to remove existing add your new menu than go to  \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\navigation\top.phtml line 46 and comment `<?php echo $_menu ?>` to remove menu and add your code here as per your requirement.

if you want to override complete navigation code than copy “app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/block/Navigation.php” to “app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/block/Navigation.php”. Create the needed directories if they do not exist. This will override Magento’s core version and will allow your changes to survive an update.

Next, open the file you just created. Find the the function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml to make any change in it